# Get each month balance with capping on redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, recursive-query

I would like to get each month balance for those records, with a capping to 500 credits at the beginning of each month.

And I am a bit stuck because I think I can't simply do a rolling sum because the maximum balance for a customer is twice the amount of his new credits (I use 500 as a maximum in the example).

Here is my data :

```
CREATE TABLE table1 as (
SELECT 'A' as customer_id, 250 as new_credits, -62 as debit, 1 as month_nb
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 250,    -84,    2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 250,    -8, 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 210,    -400,   4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 210,    -162,   5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 210,    0,  6
)
```

I would like to see these result :

[image: Result]

Any thought ? Thanks !

Comment: Are you asking how to 'limit' a value (eg using `LEAST()`), or are you asking how to reference values from previous rows (eg using a Window Function)?

Comment: I think it's more how to reference value from previous rows. I need to know the previous balance, add the new credits, and limit it to 500.

Comment: Take a look at: [LAG window function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LAG.html)

Comment: Thanks, looks very useful, but I think it's not enough for my use case because my previous row also needs to be based on its previous row, and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding a new answer because the previous answer was out-of-date.  I'm not sure what the exact syntax is for Redshift (the documentation does not seem totally updated), but here is the idea:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select month_nb, customer_id, new_credits, debit, new_credits as starting_balance
      from table1
      where month_nb = 1
      union all
      select t1.month_nb, t1.customer_id, t1.new_credits, t1.debit,
             least(500, cte.starting_balance + cte.debit + t1.new_credits)
      from cte join
           table1 t1
           on t1.month_nb = cte.month_nb + 1 and t1.customer_id = cte.customer_id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

For instance, I'm not sure if the `recursive` keyword is needed.

And [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8e1ff01680267ee8f7eba726f919f806) is a db<>fiddle using Postgres.

Comment: It's working !! Awesome ! Thank you !
I just needed to add the columns in the first sentence : 
with recursive cte(month_nb, customer_id, new_credits, debit,starting_balance) as (